# CrossFade effect in Flash with AS 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, slideshow

I'm trying to do a crossfade effect, and I have

TransitionManager.start(imageHolder, {type:Fade, direction:Transition.IN, duration:0.75});

Which makes the image fade in, but I also want the image to fade out which it doesn't do, when I change direction:Transition.IN to direction:Transition.OUT

Anyone know what I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Greensocks TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). Your life will be better for it. The same line with TweenLite would be:

```
TweenLite.to(imageHolder, 0.75, {alpha:1});
```

Then to fadeout you would do:

```
TweenLite.to(imageHolder, 0.75, {alpha:0});
```

You could also do this simple fade using a Boolean flag and on enterFrame like this:

```
var fadeIn:Boolean = true;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    var easeSpeed:Number = 0.4;
    var targetAlpha:Number = (fadeIn) ? 1 : 0;
    imageHolder.alpha += (1 - imageHolder.alpha) * easeSpeed;
}
```

just set fadeIn to true or false anywhere else in your code, and the enterframe will take care of the fading. targetAlpha is set using a [ternary operator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#conditional), that check if fadeIn is true or false. If true, then targetAlpha is set to 1, else it's set to 0. The last line in the enterFrameHandler function is a simple ease algorithm, that eases towards the target by a percentage each frame. Adjust the easeSpeed till it looks right.